Why is omitting a column that is a linear combination of other columns not considered an elementary operation in solving a system of linear equations?
Given a system of linear equations represented by the matrix equation $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Why does removing a column from $A$ that is a linear combination of other
columns change the nature of the system and not considered an elementary operation in solving a system of linear equations?

Why is omitting a null column from $A$ also not considered an elementary operation in solving a system of linear equations (if it's not)?


As far as I understand, both actions with the matrix rows do not change the system's solution.

Both your actions change the dimension of the kernel, and thus the number of possible solutions


You seem to be saying that
$$
\begin{cases}2x+3y+z=1\\ x+3y+2z=3\end{cases} \qquad\text{ and } \begin{cases}2x+z=1\\ x+2x=3\end{cases}
$$
are the same system? The second column is a linear combination of the first and third, but the two systems do not have the same solutions.

Something similar happens. The system $2x=1$ in the variables $x,y$ is not the same as the system $2x=1$ in the variable $x$.


